# Display crashes after screen lock

Tags: ubuntu, display, screen-lock

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 version on Lenovo Ideapad

Whenever I lock my laptop (or it gets locked in inactivity) and try to unlock, my display is crashing. I see a screen as below

[image]

I have another external monitor connected to this laptop and that display looks fine.

This started happening only since a couple of days. I also tried to see if there are any recent updates which caused this. But I couldn't see anything related. Here's the log.

```
Start-Date: 2022-01-09  11:22:08
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Remove: linux-headers-5.11.0-41-generic:amd64 (5.11.0-41.45~20.04.1), linux-hwe-5.11-headers-5.11.0-41:amd64 (5.11.0-41.45~20.04.1)
End-Date: 2022-01-09  11:22:10

Start-Date: 2022-01-17  06:57:33
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libsystemd0:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.13, 245.4-4ubuntu3.15), systemd-timesyncd:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.13, 245.4-4ubuntu3.15), systemd-sysv:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.13, 245.4-4ubuntu3.15), libpam-systemd:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.13, 245.4-4ubuntu3.15), systemd:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.13, 245.4-4ubuntu3.15), libnss-systemd:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.13, 245.4-4ubuntu3.15)
End-Date: 2022-01-17  06:57:40

Start-Date: 2022-01-17  06:57:44
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libgs9:amd64 (9.50~dfsg-5ubuntu4.4, 9.50~dfsg-5ubuntu4.5), ghostscript:amd64 (9.50~dfsg-5ubuntu4.4, 9.50~dfsg-5ubuntu4.5), ghostscript-x:amd64 (9.50~dfsg-5ubuntu4.4, 9.50~dfsg-5ubuntu4.5), libgs9-common:amd64 (9.50~dfsg-5ubuntu4.4, 9.50~dfsg-5ubuntu4.5)
End-Date: 2022-01-17  06:57:46

Start-Date: 2022-01-17  06:57:50
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: linux-libc-dev:amd64 (5.4.0-92.103, 5.4.0-94.106)
End-Date: 2022-01-17  06:57:50

Start-Date: 2022-01-17  06:57:54
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Install: linux-image-5.11.0-46-generic:amd64 (5.11.0-46.51~20.04.1, automatic), linux-modules-5.11.0-46-generic:amd64 (5.11.0-46.51~20.04.1, automatic), linux-headers-5.11.0-46-generic:amd64 (5.11.0-46.51~20.04.1, automatic), linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-46-generic:amd64 (5.11.0-46.51~20.04.1, automatic), linux-hwe-5.11-headers-5.11.0-46:amd64 (5.11.0-46.51~20.04.1, automatic)
Upgrade: linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 (5.11.0.44.48~20.04.22, 5.11.0.46.51~20.04.23), linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 (5.11.0.44.48~20.04.22, 5.11.0.46.51~20.04.23), linux-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 (5.11.0.44.48~20.04.22, 5.11.0.46.51~20.04.23)
End-Date: 2022-01-17  06:58:33

Start-Date: 2022-01-17  06:58:36
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: python3-pil:amd64 (7.0.0-4ubuntu0.4, 7.0.0-4ubuntu0.5)
End-Date: 2022-01-17  06:58:37

Start-Date: 2022-01-17  06:58:41
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: udev:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.13, 245.4-4ubuntu3.15), libudev1:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.13, 245.4-4ubuntu3.15)
End-Date: 2022-01-17  06:58:57

Start-Date: 2022-01-17  06:59:00
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: firefox:amd64 (95.0.1+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 96.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
End-Date: 2022-01-17  06:59:05

Start-Date: 2022-01-17  06:59:09
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: firefox-locale-en:amd64 (95.0.1+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 96.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
End-Date: 2022-01-17  06:59:09

Start-Date: 2022-01-17  06:59:13
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libexiv2-27:amd64 (0.27.2-8ubuntu2.6, 0.27.2-8ubuntu2.7)
End-Date: 2022-01-17  06:59:13

Start-Date: 2022-01-18  06:46:44
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Remove: linux-image-5.11.0-43-generic:amd64 (5.11.0-43.47~20.04.2), linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-43-generic:amd64 (5.11.0-43.47~20.04.2), linux-modules-5.11.0-43-generic:amd64 (5.11.0-43.47~20.04.2)
End-Date: 2022-01-18  06:46:50

Start-Date: 2022-01-18  06:46:53
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Remove: linux-headers-5.11.0-43-generic:amd64 (5.11.0-43.47~20.04.2)
End-Date: 2022-01-18  06:46:54

Start-Date: 2022-01-18  06:46:58
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Remove: linux-hwe-5.11-headers-5.11.0-43:amd64 (5.11.0-43.47~20.04.2)
End-Date: 2022-01-18  06:46:58

Start-Date: 2022-01-19  06:44:47
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Install: linux-modules-5.13.0-25-generic:amd64 (5.13.0-25.26~20.04.1, automatic), linux-headers-5.13.0-25-generic:amd64 (5.13.0-25.26~20.04.1, automatic), linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-25-generic:amd64 (5.13.0-25.26~20.04.1, automatic), linux-image-5.13.0-25-generic:amd64 (5.13.0-25.26~20.04.1, automatic), linux-hwe-5.13-headers-5.13.0-25:amd64 (5.13.0-25.26~20.04.1, automatic)
Upgrade: linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 (5.11.0.46.51~20.04.23, 5.13.0.25.26~20.04.12), linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 (5.11.0.46.51~20.04.23, 5.13.0.25.26~20.04.12), linux-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 (5.11.0.46.51~20.04.23, 5.13.0.25.26~20.04.12)
End-Date: 2022-01-19  06:45:27

Start-Date: 2022-01-20  10:25:32
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Remove: linux-headers-5.11.0-44-generic:amd64 (5.11.0-44.48~20.04.2), linux-hwe-5.11-headers-5.11.0-44:amd64 (5.11.0-44.48~20.04.2)
End-Date: 2022-01-20  10:25:34

Start-Date: 2022-01-20  10:25:37
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Remove: linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-44-generic:amd64 (5.11.0-44.48~20.04.2)
End-Date: 2022-01-20  10:25:38

Start-Date: 2022-01-20  10:25:42
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Remove: linux-modules-5.11.0-44-generic:amd64 (5.11.0-44.48~20.04.2), linux-image-5.11.0-44-generic:amd64 (5.11.0-44.48~20.04.2)
End-Date: 2022-01-20  10:25:46

Start-Date: 2022-01-20  10:25:51
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: linux-libc-dev:amd64 (5.4.0-94.106, 5.4.0-96.109)
End-Date: 2022-01-20  10:25:51

Start-Date: 2022-01-20  10:25:55
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Install: linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-27-generic:amd64 (5.13.0-27.29~20.04.1, automatic), linux-modules-5.13.0-27-generic:amd64 (5.13.0-27.29~20.04.1, automatic), linux-headers-5.13.0-27-generic:amd64 (5.13.0-27.29~20.04.1, automatic), linux-image-5.13.0-27-generic:amd64 (5.13.0-27.29~20.04.1, automatic), linux-hwe-5.13-headers-5.13.0-27:amd64 (5.13.0-27.29~20.04.1, automatic)
Upgrade: linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 (5.13.0.25.26~20.04.12, 5.13.0.27.29~20.04.13), linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 (5.13.0.25.26~20.04.12, 5.13.0.27.29~20.04.13), linux-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 (5.13.0.25.26~20.04.12, 5.13.0.27.29~20.04.13)
End-Date: 2022-01-20  10:26:34

Start-Date: 2022-01-21  09:54:26
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Remove: linux-headers-5.11.0-46-generic:amd64 (5.11.0-46.51~20.04.1), linux-hwe-5.11-headers-5.11.0-46:amd64 (5.11.0-46.51~20.04.1)
End-Date: 2022-01-21  09:54:28

Start-Date: 2022-01-21  09:54:32
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Remove: linux-image-5.11.0-46-generic:amd64 (5.11.0-46.51~20.04.1), linux-modules-5.11.0-46-generic:amd64 (5.11.0-46.51~20.04.1), linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-46-generic:amd64 (5.11.0-46.51~20.04.1)
End-Date: 2022-01-21  09:54:37
```

I have a dual boot. So tried the same on Windows and it works perfectly fine even after locking the screen. I don't know if any video drivers are disturbed in Ubuntu. Any help please!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an Lenovo latop (AMD architecture) with the same issue. The problem is in newest update of kernel 5.13 newer.

Check your kernel version by typing this command

```
uname -r
```

If you have a version 5.13 or newer you can fix the issue by downgrading to a lower version such as 5.11.

**It is not a final solution but it can help you until the new patch will be released.**

There are some tutorials which can be useful:

- [install and boot an older kernel](https://serverascode.com/2019/05/17/install-and-boot-older-kernel-ubuntu.html)
- [remove an old (unused) kernel](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/ubuntu-remove-old-kernels)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [Du Dy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/511111/du-dy) in his [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/687461/511058), I checked the kernel version and it indeed was 5.13.

Then, I checked what other versions were there before 5.13 got installed, by doing:

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-image
```

Picked an older version 5.11.0-44 and installed it again

```
sudo apt install linux-image-5.11.0-44-generic
```

And booted into this 5.11 kernel. It solved the display problem but many things were not working. Like network, external display, etc...

Tried to compare what all installations are present for other installed kernels by doing a `dpkg --list | grep linux-` and found out that modules-extra package was missing for 5.11

Booted back to the new kernel (the one working but with display problem) and installed the missing package

```
sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-44-generic
```

Booted into 5.11 and everything works perfect